# I can't enlarge my footer to take all the space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to enlarge my footer so it can take the all page and stick to the bottom (not following when scrolling), but I have no idea how to do it...
here's the result I have on my website : [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXCrH.jpg)

Here's my code : https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/RwLaJye

```css
footer {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #613B6A;
}

div .Question {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: right;
}
    div .Question a {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

div .Logo img{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 18%;
    box-shadow: none;
}

div .Copyright {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer> 

  <div class="Logo">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Bn1t4Nc9/Game-Star-Blanc.png">
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="Question">
    <p>Une question ?<br> <a href="">Contactez-nous!</a>
    </p>
  </div>
<br>

  <div class="Copyright">© 2021 Copyright: GameStar - La Star des références gaming.</div>

</footer>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
footer {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #613B6A;
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: i did, guess it looks like it works but not well here's the result : https://ibb.co/4RXTYdt

it got shifted to the right

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

See here:

```css
footer {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #613B6A;
}

div .Question {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: right;
}
    div .Question a {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

div .Logo img{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 18%;
    box-shadow: none;
}

div .Copyright {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer> 

  <div class="Logo">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Bn1t4Nc9/Game-Star-Blanc.png">
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="Question">
    <p>Une question ?<br> <a href="">Contactez-nous!</a>
    </p>
  </div>
<br>

  <div class="Copyright">© 2021 Copyright: GameStar - La Star des références gaming.</div>

</footer>
```

Comment: it doesn't work :/

Comment: @Softee mind commenting your codepen with all the code?

Answer (score 0):

You made your logo size to be 100% of your footer, you need to resize the logo smaller and float it left, then clearing the float to show the centered the text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).